# Why does this comparison fail in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I want to truncate 'signal_out' to be within -8192 and +8192 (14 bit signed.)

I do this in Verilog:

```
    reg signed  [25:0] reg_out;
    .
    ,
    ,
    
    assign signal_out = ( reg_out > 14'd8191 ) ? 14'd8191 : ( reg_out < -14'd8191 ) ? -14'd8191 : reg_out[13:0];
```

Without this limiter, the output is correct - currently between -6800 and +6800. Using this line I always get -8191.

As far as I know, when comparing two signed values with different width, the shorter value is expanded preserving the sign.

What's wrong with this line?

Keep in mind, the code is for synthesis, not only for simulation.

Comment: There is no point in restricting the size of the compare, there is no saving that won't be done during optimisation anyway. In any case, the upper bits of the array are relivant for negative numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still new to Verilog (being from a VHDL background) but I would suggest don't use slices with signed values. Instead assign to a saturated intermediate, and then assign a slice of the result.

I usually try and avoid implied behaviour as that assumes different synthesis engines behave the same (which is far from the case) resulting in instant portability issues, possible simulation/synthesis mismatch and longer term latest bugs.

Here an example written <strike>(from memory and untested)</strike> as a Verilog module but perhaps would be better as a function in SystemVerilog (Not provided here for brevity. Also in SV I'd use a type e.g. sint_32, rather than an array as it's much more readable. But that's probably because I prefer explicit typing)

**Update 9/1/23**: In response to (an unexplained??) downvote I've update the answer to prove it is correct.

- Corrected some syntax in the module (oritinal was written from memory)
- Added a test bench and simulation results (Vivado 2022)

```
module clip_signed #(
  parameter unsigned n_bits_ip = 16,
  parameter unsigned n_bits_op = 14
)(
  input signed [n_bits_ip-1:0] val_ip,
  output signed [n_bits_op-1:0] val_op
);

 wire signed [n_bits_ip-1:0] value;

 parameter signed [n_bits_ip-1:0] max_op = (2**(n_bits_op-1)) - 1;
 parameter signed [n_bits_ip-1:0] min_op = -(2**(n_bits_op-1));

 assign value = (val_ip > max_op)?max_op:(val_ip < min_op)?min_op:val_ip;
 assign val_op = value[n_bits_op-1:0];

endmodule
```

```
module sim_clip_signed ();

parameter size_ip = 16;
parameter size_op = 14;

parameter max_ip = (2**(size_ip-1))-1;
parameter min_ip = -(2**(size_ip-1));

reg [size_ip-1:0] data_ip;
wire [size_op-1:0] data_op;

clip_signed #(
    .n_bits_ip (size_ip),
    .n_nits_op (size_op)
) uut (
    .val_ip (data_ip),
    .val_op (data_op)
);

integer loop;

initial begin
  for (loop = min_ip; loop < max_ip; loop = loop + 1) begin
    assign data_ip = loop[size_ip-1:0];
    #10;
  end
  $finish;
end
  
endmodule
```

[image: Simulation waveform]

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing `reg signed [25:0` with `-14'd8191`. However, that constant is actually *unsigned*. When you have unsigned and signed operands in an expression, unsigned wins, so the comparison is done using unsigned arithmetic.

Try writing `-14'sd8191` to see if that makes a difference.